# Application build on Android2.2 platform not working on emulator of 2.3.3 platform

Tags: android, android-version

I am new in android, Please help me ....
I build an application in android 2.2platform but when i test it on an emulator of version 2.3.3 and higher it is not working .
Is there any problem of emulators or I have to build the same application with the 2.3.3 platform .....???

Comment: @oriolpons : Sir I am running the application from installing the .apk file in emulator so can't paste log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your AndroidManifest.xml has a line like the following:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"
          android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
```

This says, essentially, "I would like to target 2.2 devices, but the application should run on any devices up to 2.3.4."

You can get more information about uses-sdk at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Manifest file in that is there any code like ? If yes then remove that line and then test it or set that at which level you want to run your application.